# Configuration file format, complex datastructures (list, dictionaries), comments, editable

Tags: python, config

I have long used normal python files for configuration purposes. I can include comments (to remind me what an entry was all about if the variable name isn't sufficient) and supports lists and dictionaries.

Now that I need to have something for a customer importing this seems a bit dangerous as it could break the system if they make an error editing by hand.

In the future I want to be able to update the file from within a program, and also be able to edit it  with a normal editor ( and prefer not having to match `<>` or `()`:

- XML is inappropriate as it is binary in ascii disguise
- .ini files have to little hierarchical structure
- JSON cannot handle comments.

I am now considering adding comments to JSON, but that essentially would require rewriting the parser to preserve comments. And JSON is not that nicely readable.

There is a ConfigObj library for `.ini` files that preserves comments, but the `.ini` is to flat for my needs (lists of dicts containing values that are lists of dicts).

Is there some other config file format I should use? Or should I look at parsing my `.py` files in  safe way before importing them (that also allows writing them out again)?

Comment: You might look at YAML (I'm not sure at a glance whether it supports your requirements). Alternatively, you can simply include comments in your JSON under a 'comments' key. It may seem like a kludge, but it has the added benefit that your comments can be parsed and manipulated easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chazeon and jme indicate you should take a look at YAML. It supports nested data structures ( list (sequence in YAML), dict (mapping) and various primitives ( integers, float, string, date ).

YAML also supports end-of-line comments ( introduced with `#`) but the "standard" [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) parser mentioned by Chazeon throws these away while reading data in (and cannot write these).

The package [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/0.7.2) (of which I am the author) that derives from PyYAML, preserves the comments when doing a round trip (YAML file to python datastructures to YAML file). It also keeps most of the YAML formatting (block vs. one-line for lists and dictionaries).

Indentation however is "standardised" so all block mappings and sequences look the same after the first roundtrip. Indentation defaults to 2 spaces for both, but these can be set separately, as well as that the dash can be "pushed in" within the space before the sequence element using e.g. `yaml.indent(mapping=3, sequence=5, offset=2)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered YAML? It can have comments start with `#` and some parsers like [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) already exsists.

As far as I know, some relatively large programs like MongoDB is using YAML as configuration file, and some programs use YAML to store metadata in front of a file, for example, Pandoc support yaml in front of Markdown and .

For further information you can visit the [The Official YAML Website](http://yaml.org/) which presented some good examples and a bunch information or the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

For me (Just my opinion)

I will use JSON since it is small, easy to read and compatible with almost any language and platform.
For comment, I will use some keyword e.g. "Comment" and assign it as a JSON tag. JSON will ignore unused tags anyway.

Example of JSON

```
{
    "param1" : "value1",
    "param2" : "value2",
}
```

Example of JSON with my comment

```
{
    "param1" : "value1",
    "param2" : "value2",
    "Comment" : "My Comment."
}
```

By the way, from my experience, we can't rely on customer to edit any formatted data JSON, XML, ini or even YAML. They will brake somethings.