# How to use custom dictionary class while loading yaml?

Tags: python, pyyaml

I am currently loading a YAML file like this

```
 import yaml
 yaml.load('''level0:
                 stuff: string0
                 level1: 
                     stuff: string1
                     level2: ...''')
```

The code above creates *nested dictionaries*. 
Instead of creating nested dictionaries, I want to create nested instances of `FancyDict` objects.

```
class FancyDict(collections.MutableMapping):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       for name in kwargs:
          setattr(self, name, kwargs[name])
```

The section on [Constructors, Representer, Resolvers](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers)
doesn't seem to address this case where I want to globally override the class 
construction for all dictionaries instead of special tagged ones.

I just need a hook that would be called a object (node?) is created/finalized.
Is there a easy way to do this or should I just traverse the nested dictionaries that a `yaml.load` returns to me and fix them myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That hook is not there, the type that is constructed is hard-coded in `construct.BaseConstructor.construct_mapping()`.

The way to solve this is make your own constructor and based on that your own loader, and hand that one in as option for `load()`:

```
import sys
import collections
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
level0:
  stuff: string0
  level1:
    stuff: string1
    level2: ...
"""

from ruamel.yaml.reader import Reader
from ruamel.yaml.scanner import Scanner
from ruamel.yaml.parser import Parser
from ruamel.yaml.composer import Composer
from ruamel.yaml.constructor import SafeConstructor
from ruamel.yaml.resolver import Resolver
from ruamel.yaml.nodes import MappingNode


class FancyDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for name in kwargs:
            setattr(self, name, kwargs[name])

    # provide the missing __getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__, __iter__, and __len__.

class MyConstructor(SafeConstructor):
    def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
        res = SafeConstructor.construct_mapping(self, node, deep)
        assert isinstance(res, dict)
        return FancyDict(**res)


class MyLoader(Reader, Scanner, Parser, Composer, MyConstructor, Resolver):
    def __init__(self, stream, version=None):
        Reader.__init__(self, stream)
        Scanner.__init__(self)
        Parser.__init__(self)
        Composer.__init__(self)
        MyConstructor.__init__(self)
        Resolver.__init__(self)


data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=MyLoader)
```

When you run this you'll get an error that FancyDict is an abstract class that cannot be instantiated:

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FancyDict with abstract methods `__delitem__`, `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`, `__setitem__`

I guess your real `FancyDict` has those implemented.

---

<sub>ruamel.yaml is a YAML library that supports YAML 1.2 (I recommend using that, but then I am the author of the package). PyYAML only supports (most of) YAML 1.1. More problematically, it has different `constructor.py` files for Python2 and Python3, you might not be able to drop in the above code in PyYAML because of that.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that actually works on PyYaml.

```
class Loader(yaml.FullLoader):

    def construct_yaml_map(self, node):
        data = MyDictionaryClass()
        yield data
        value = self.construct_mapping(node)
        data.update(value)

Loader.add_constructor(
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:map',
    Loader.construct_yaml_map
)
```

The issue with using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631057/754991) is that PyYaml converts the mapping back into a dictionary on the `construct_yaml_map` function. Just replacing this function in a subclass isn't enough because of the custom `add_constructor` added for SafeLoader so you can overwrite it to use the new `construct_yaml_map` for your class.