# Parse a list in yaml into a python set

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

Is it possible to parse lists in a yaml file directly into a python [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) by default ?
If the answer is yes, how can I achieve this?

E.g.:

```
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader

# Open the file and load the file
with open('Userdetails.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
    print(data)
```

Expected Output:

```
{'User': {'user1', 'user2'}}
```

Instead of:

```
{'User': ['user1', 'user2']}
```

And without looping through the dictionary after load.

Comment: And what does `Userdetails.yaml` look like? Why are you using PyYAML, it only supports YAML 1.1, outdated in 2009.

Comment: your expected output looks more like a dictionary than a set

Comment: You should be able to do something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629559/how-to-use-custom-dictionary-class-while-loading-yaml by implementing a custom `Loader.construct_sequence`.

Comment: the yaml loader generates a Dictionary by default. set([user1,user2]) == {user1,user2}

Comment: @mkrieger1 that goes into the right direction !

Answer (score 0):

If i right understand you, thats simple:

```
data = set(yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader))
```

Comment: How does this create sets instead of lists?

Comment: No, I mean the list inside of a yaml should be parsed as a set instead of a list. And i know that i can loop  through entries in the outcoming dict Checking the instance and run a type Casting. But this is not what i want to do.  thanks for given a try.

Answer (score -1):

What you provided as an example is not a `set` - it is a `dict`.

PyYAML parses data into `dict`s already - you should be pretty much good to go.

Comment: No, the entry of the Dictionary is a set